# Safari 13.1.1 history, website data and cache cleaning with a single script

Tags: cookies, safari, browser-cache, history

Hello dear Stackoverflow community,

I am looking in vain for an applescript with which I can delete the history, the website data, the cookies and the cache in my Safari browser 13.1.1. Unfortunately I only find scripts for older browser versions.
So far I've been experimenting with the following script only for the website data, but it may not work:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
        keystroke "," using command down
        delay 1
        click button "Privacy" of toolbar 1 of window 1 
        click button "Manage Website Data…" of group 1 of group 1 of window "Privacy"
        delay 3
        click button "Remove All"
        click button "Done" 
end tell
```

Since I am using the German Safari version, I have replaced the following terms:

- "Privacy" → "Datenschutz"
- "Manage Website Data…" → "Websitedaten verwalten ..."
- "Remove All" → "Alle entfernen"
- "Done" → "Fertig"

So my script looks like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
            keystroke "," using command down
            delay 1
            click button "Datenschutz" of toolbar 1 of window 1 
            click button "Websitedaten verwalten …" of group 1 of group 1 of window "Datenschutz"
            delay 3
            click button "Alle entfernen"
            click button "Fertig" 
    end tell
```

Unfortunately it does not work even then and I assume that this script does not fit for Safari 13.1.1.
Can someone help me here?

However, I have to confess that I am not very well versed in programming.

Kind regards and thank you ever

Andy